# User registration factory for AngularJS + Firebase app

Tags: javascript, beginner, angular.js, asynchronous, firebase

The goal for this code is to provide a semi-secure and privileged method of user registration via a secret code that is stored as a key in the Firebase database.

Subscribers to a mailing list were all sent a 'secret' registration code. Upon completion of the registration form, `RegisterFactory.register` is called from the controller. One of my biggest concerns is that I have to make 5 async calls all of which return a promise and results in a long chain of promises.

The app has been in use for a month without any major issue. Before the next session starts, I would like to improve things a bit.

Please ignore the code where I un-authenticate the user as this issue needs to be fixed elsewhere first. Once fixed, I should be able to return the last Firebase promise to the controller.

The relevant Firebase schema is:

```
{
    "secretKey": true,

    "clientList": {
        "paid": {...}
    },

    "users": {
        "$userID": {
            "profile": {...}
        }
    }
```

RegisterFactory:

```
app.factory('RegisterFactory', ['AuthRefService', 'APP', '$q', 'appFunctions',
            function(AuthRefService, APP, $q, appFunctions){

    /**
     *  Precondition: A data structure of { 'secretKey': 'secretValue' },
     *  Postcondition: Returns a promise with the data at '/code' resolving with
     *      'secretValue' or null.
    */
    var checkCode = function(code){
        code = code.trim();
        var ref = new Firebase(APP.BASEURL);
        return ref.child(code).once('value');
    };

    /**
     *  Precondition: checkCode(code) resolves with true.
     *  Postcondition: A new user is created in Firebase and returns a 
     *      promise resolving with userData (that only contains userData.uid and does not auth user) or error.
    */
    var createUser = function(credentials) {
        return AuthRefService.$createUser({
            email: credentials.email,
            password: credentials.password
        });
    };

    /**
     *  Precondition: checkCode(code) resolves with true.
     *  Postcondition: User is authenticated is and a promise resovles with authData or error 
    */
    var authUser = function(credentials) {
        return AuthRefService.$authWithPassword({
            email: credentials.email,
            password: credentials.password
        });  
    };

    /**
    *   Precondition: User is authenticated.
    *   Postcondition: Sets data at: /user/uid/profile and returns a
    *       promise resoloving w/o data if success, otherwise with error
    */
    var setProfile = function(authData, profile){
        var ref = new Firebase(APP.BASEURL + "users/" + authData.uid);
        return ref.child("profile").set(profile);
    };

    /**
    *   Precondition: User is authenticated.
    *   Postcondition: Sets data at: /clientList/paid and returns a
    *       promise resoloving w/o data if success, otherwise with error
    */
    var addToClientList = function(data, uid) {
        var now = appFunctions.dateToNum(new Date());  // yyyyMMdd
        var info = {
            first: data.profile.first,
            last: data.profile.last,
            email: data.credentials.email,
            dateJoined: now
        };

        var ref = new Firebase(APP.BASEURL + "clientList/paid");

        return ref.child(uid).set(info);
    };    

    return {
        /**
        *   Precondition: user input, data, is complete
        *   Postcondition: A new user is created in database
        */
        register: function(data) {
            return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                checkCode(data.credentials.code)
                .then(function(snapshot){
                    if(snapshot) {
                        createUser(data.credentials)
                        .then(function(userData) {
                            console.log("User create with id:", userData.uid);
                            authUser(data.credentials)
                            .then(function(authData) {
                                setProfile(authData, data.profile)
                                .then(function(resp) {

                                    // store new user in clientList index
                                    addToClientList(data, authData.uid)
                                    .then(function(resp) {
                                        // TODO: deal with this better
                                        // logout user, b/c I couldn't figure out a solution to smoothly get the new
                                        //   user to '/app' b/c of how app inits user upon login.
                                        AuthRefService.$unauth();
                                        resolve(true);
                                    }, function(err){
                                        if (typeof err !== "string") {
                                            err = "Error";
                                        }
                                        reject(err);
                                    });

                                }, function(err) {
                                    if (typeof err !== "string") {
                                        err = "Error";
                                    }
                                    reject(err);
                                });

                            }, function(err) {
                                if (typeof err !== "string") {
                                    err = "Error";
                                }
                                reject(err);
                            });

                        }, function(err) {
                            if (typeof err !== "string") {
                                err = "Error";
                            }
                            reject(err);
                        });
                    } else {
                        reject("Error");
                    }


                }, function(err){
                    reject("Invalid Registration Code");
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return {
    /**
    *   Precondition: user input, data, is complete
    *   Postcondition: A new user is created in database
    */
    register: function(data) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            checkCode(data.credentials.code)
            .then(function(snapshot){
                if(snapshot) {
                    createUser(data.credentials)
                    .then(function(userData) {
                        console.log("User create with id:", userData.uid);
                        authUser(data.credentials)
                        .then(function(authData) {
                            setProfile(authData, data.profile)
                            .then(function(resp) {

                                // store new user in clientList index
                                addToClientList(data, authData.uid)
                                .then(function(resp) {
                                    // TODO: deal with this better
                                    // logout user, b/c I couldn't figure out a solution to smoothly get the new
                                    //   user to '/app' b/c of how app inits user upon login.
                                    AuthRefService.$unauth();
                                    resolve(true);
                                }, function(err){
                                    if (typeof err !== "string") {
                                        err = "Error";
                                    }
                                    reject(err);
                                });

                            }, function(err) {
                                if (typeof err !== "string") {
                                    err = "Error";
                                }
                                reject(err);
                            });

                        }, function(err) {
                            if (typeof err !== "string") {
                                err = "Error";
                            }
                            reject(err);
                        });

                    }, function(err) {
                        if (typeof err !== "string") {
                            err = "Error";
                        }
                        reject(err);
                    });
                } else {
                    reject("Error");
                }


            }, function(err){
                reject("Invalid Registration Code");
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Wwwoooaaahhh! :D

Anyways, you're using promises wrong here. Promises were designed to *prevent* this thing from happening. Straight to the point, how promises prevent this is something similar to the following:

```
asyncOperation1().then(() => {

  // asyncOperation1 done
  return asyncOperation2();

}).then(() => {

  // asyncOperation2 done
  return asyncOperation3();

}).then(() => {

  // asyncOperation3 done

});
```

When you return a promise inside a `then` (`asyncOperation2`), the return of `then` is a promise that resolves when `asyncOperation2` resolves. You end up writing code that's fairly linear-looking.

Also, there's also the `catch` method. Any unhandled rejections in promise chain will be caught by a `catch` similar to how a `try-catch` would do it. But note that adding a `catch` will allow the promise to recover, this succeeding `then`s will resolve unless `catch` rethrows the error.

Anyways, your entire operation could be simplified to:

```
function (data){
    return checkCode(data.credentials.code)
    .then( snapshot => {
        // Note that we can forcefully reject by returning a rejected promise.
        // We can do that with `Promise.reject`.
        return !snapshot ? Promise.reject('Error') : createUser(data.credentials);
    })
    .then( userData => {
        return authUser(data.credentials);
    })
    .then( authData => {
        // We need to pass through `authData` to the next then so `addToClientList`
        // can use it. We attach a `then` to `setProfile` that resolves with
        // `authData` and `resp` so that the next then receives it as `profile`
        return setProfile(authData, data.profile).then( resp => { authData, resp });
    })
    .then( profile => {
        return addToClientList(data, profile.authData.uid);
    })
    .then( resp => {
        AuthRefService.$unauth();
    });

    // No need for catch. Should any errors happen, the entire thing will be a
    // return a rejected promise which the caller can handle instead.
}
```

Comment: I wish I had posted here a few months ago! I've wasted soooo much time 'researching' on my own. Thanks a bunch for explaining this!